# Is there any way to get the page results of which an ID belongs to? Without knowing page number?

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch, pagination, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have a messageId from elastic search.
Need to get only the page results where that ID belongs, without knowing the pagenumber.
Suppose I have 4 pages (with no of records per page 20), and message id is 123456.
When sorting in ascending, that message with id 123456 lies on the 3rd page.
In that case can i get the 3rd page results only as response?
Also need to get the pagenumber and from and to count.

I'm using elasticsearch boolquery and Java (Spring boot)

Can we get this without Iteration?
This is kind of reverse pagination

Comment: Seems like an XY problem - what is the use case?

Comment: @AndrewS after searching a message based on text, if user clicks on one search result, need to go to that particular page of messages. 
We have only message id in that case

Comment: _if user clicks on one search result_... then it seems that single message should be displayed.

Comment: @AndrewS no as per requirement it should go to that page where message belongs

Comment: hmm, well maybe the _search_after_ parameter could be used based on the original search results.